# ios - UILabel text resets to very tiny font size when I try to put longer text into it

Tags: ios, ios5, uilabel

I have a screen I am working on like this:

[image]

On top is a UILabel that I fetch from the remote database and replace with whatever the default is. 
When the value of that string is long, the system resets the font size to very small like in this emulator screen shot:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent it from doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1- change no. of lines of text of uilabel to 2

2- uncheck the auto shrink flag